# How does the size of managed code affect memory footprint?

Tags: memory-management, windows-ce

I have been tasked with reducing memory footprint of a `Windows CE 5.0` application. I came across [Rob Tiffany's highly cited article](http://robtiffany.com/memmaker-for-the-net-compact-framework/) which recommends using managed DLL to keep the code out of the process's slot. But there is something I don't understand.

The article says that

> The JIT compiler is running in your slot and it pulls in IL from the 1
>   GB space as needed to compile the current call stack.

This means that all the code in the managed DLL can potentially eventually end up in the process's slot. While this will help *other processes* by not loading the code in common area how does it help *this process*? FWIW the article does mention that

> It also reduces the amount of memory that has to be allocated inside your

My only thought is that just as the code is pulled into the slot it is also pushed/swapped out. But that is just a wild guess and probably completely false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF assemblies aren't loaded into the process slot like native DLLs are.  They're actually accessed as memory-mapped files.  This means that the size of the DLL is effectively irrelevant.

The managed heap also lies in shared memory, not your process slot, so object allocations are far less likely to cause process slot fragmentation or OOM's.

The JITter also doesn't just JIT and hold forever.  It compiles what is necessary, and during a GC may very well pitch compiled code that is not being used, or that hasn't been used in a while.  You're never going to see an entire assembly JITTed and pulled into the process slow (well if it's a small assembly maybe, but it's certainly not typical).

Obviously some process slot memory has to be used to create some pointers, stack storage, etc etc, but by and large managed code has way less impact on the process slot limitations than native code.  Of course you can still hit the limit with large stacks, P/Invokes, native allocations and the like.

In my experience, the area people get into trouble most often with CF apps an memory is with GDI objects and drawing.  Bitmaps take up a lot of memory.  Even though it's largely in shared memory, creating lots of them (along with brushes, pens, etc) and not caching and reusing is what most often give a large managed app memory footprint.

For a bit more detail [this MSDN webcast on Compact Framework Memory Management](https://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/EventDetail.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032318791&CountryCode=US), while old, is still very relevant.

Comment: Thank you for elaborate response.